# How to unlock a database after changing CONNECT_PROC

Tags: stored-procedures, connection, db2

I executed this script in DB2 10.1, and after that, I do not know how to reestablish the database connection:

script.sql

```
--#SET TERMINATOR @
SET CURRENT SCHEMA BLOCK_DB @
CREATE PROCEDURE BLOCK_DB.A ()
BEGIN
END @
CREATE PROCEDURE BLOCK_DB.B ()
BEGIN
 CALL BLOCK_DB.A ();
END @
--#SET TERMINATOR ;
UPDATE DB CFG USING CONNECT_PROC BLOCK_DB.B;
DROP PROCEDURE BLOCK_DB.A ();
CONNECT RESET;
```

I executed like this

```
db2 -tf script.sql
```

After that, I tried to reconnect, but it was unsuccessful.

```
db2 connect to sample
```

DO NOT TRY THIS IN A PRODUCTION ENVIRONMENT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply reset the value of `CONNECT_PROC`:

```
db2 "update db cfg for <db> using connect_proc ''"
```

You do not need to have a database connection to execute this statement.  This will set CONNECT_PROC back to the default (NULL), and you'll be able to connect to the database again.